# php string encoding and web service

Tags: php, mysql, string, character-encoding

I'm trying  to manage PHP strings with accents and no success. (sorry for my poor english).
Well, I read a string from a MySQL table:

```
$array_select[$i]['TestoDomanda'] = htmlspecialchars_decode( htmlentities( trim($array_select[$i]['TestoDomanda']), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8" ) );
```

the table has utf8 - default collation and this is how the connection is established:

```
 try {
                    self::$conn = new PDO(
                                $string_dsn, 
                                $user, 
                                $password,
                                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")     // configuring mysql connection
                    ); 
            }
```

in the header of HTML pages I have

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and visualization in browser is ok. I'm using eclipse and seems that my .php files are saved using utf-8.

I send this string to an online webservice, creating an http request and receiving a JSON object:

```
//$_testoDomanda is "Qual era il vero nome del comico Totò?"    
$testoDomanda = **urlencode**( $_testoDomanda);  // problem: ò become someting like %26ograve%3B%3F and the web service ignores the last word (tot%26ograve%3B%3F)
// I will prefere to have **"toto"** instead of **"totò"** for correct encoding

$json = new Services_JSON(); 
$request = "http://176. (.. *omissis*..) =1&q=".$testoDomanda;
$arrayResponse = file($request);
            (...)
```

If the string contains accents, the accented word is ignored.. so if $testoDomanda is "Qual era il vero nome del comico Totò?" the server will receive "Qual era il vero nome del comico "
I've tryied a lot of tricks for solving this, but I think I've some encodin problem, because var_dump($testoDomanda) returns a wrong length (45).
These are some attempts I made:

```
$testoDomanda = urlencode(htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($_testoDomanda) ));  // Qual+era+il+vero+nome+del+comico+Tot%26ograve%3B%3F
$testoDomanda = urlencode(htmlentities($_testoDomanda, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"));           // Qual+era+il+vero+nome+del+comico+Tot%26amp%3Bograve%3B%3F
$testoDomanda = urlencode(htmlentities($_testoDomanda,1));                          // Qual+era+il+vero+nome+del+comico+Tot%26amp%3Bograve%3B%3F
```

I also tryied to replace character like "ò" whith "o" (searching "Toto" will work) but preg_replace() nor str_replace() found "ò" in my variable.. 
EDIT:
I used this function (for example) for replacing acents:

```
function replace_accents($stringa) {
        $stringa=preg_replace("/è/","e",$stringa);
        $stringa=preg_replace("/é/","e",$stringa);
        $stringa=preg_replace("/ò/","o",$stringa);
        $stringa=preg_replace("/à/","a",$stringa);
        $stringa=preg_replace("/ì/","i",$stringa);
        return $stringa;
    }
```

why this?
The final question is how to fix a string behaving in strange mode (var_dump, str_replace, preg_replace not working as aspected) with accents or how to replace accented characters with non-accented counterpart.
Please help me, I don't know how to fix this...
Thanks

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the web service does not handle accented characters?  Let's see how you tried to replace the characters?

Comment: What is that for a chaos code? Are you talking to some specific database or are you just trying which command works? What is your actual question? Reduce the code only to the relevant part please. I'd say three lines maximum.

Comment: Whooaaaa... you're using PDO and then `mysql_query()`?  How's that?

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions as they are [in the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Try out what mb_internal_encoding can do for you.

Comment: I used this function for replacing acents: 
`function replace_accents($stringa) {
  $stringa=preg_replace("/è/","e",$stringa);
  $stringa=preg_replace("/é/","e",$stringa);
  $stringa=preg_replace("/ò/","o",$stringa);
  $stringa=preg_replace("/à/","a",$stringa);
  $stringa=preg_replace("/ì/","i",$stringa);
  echo " . . . $stringa . . . ";
  return $stringa;
 }`

Comment: the caos of code I reported is to avoid common suggestion That I already found in other discussion ("set utf-8 for db connection" etc).
`mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` doesn't change anithing. I can't know if the webservice can handle accents.. so replacing "àèò" whit "aeo" can be a working idea.

Comment: What exactly is returned by the web-service (before any replacements on your side): `ò`  or `&ograve;`? Have you tried receiving the web-service with a header `Accept-Charset:utf-8;`?

Comment: When I send that question to the server, ("Qual era il vero nome del comico Totò?) i receive the answer for the question "Qual era il vero nome del comico ", so I understand that the last word is ignored (or skipped). The question is obtained from a database, and is correctly displayed in the browser, but var_dump, preg_replace or str_replace are not working. I'm trying to replace "Totò" with "Toto" but str_replace and preg_replace doesn't found any "ò" in the string...

Comment: howevew, the web service can send also accents to me and I can display this correctly. The problem is urlencoding a string with accents, or replacing these accents